# Do I need to create a new Struts Action class for each and every request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am new to struts and I have a basic doubt in Struts.

I have created a new webpage which contains 10 links (link1, link2,......link10). When clicking on each link it should link to corresponding pages. My question is do I need to create 10 new Struts Action classes to perform redirection or do I have any other way that deals with single Struts Action class that can handle all the 10 links.

Comment: It's up to you how do you want to simplify it. If actions belong to a same domain do it one action or else split it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It dependents upon what all those 10 links will be doing.There are couple of options here.

1. If all you links are doing same type of work (e.g user related work), its better to create one action with multiple methods.

S2 provides way to define method for each action mapping and based on the method name S2 will call respected method of your action like

```
<action name="action1" class="myActionClass" method="method1"/>
<action name="action2" class="myActionClass" method="method2"/>
```

Note that create an Action class with method only if you have some sort of logic needs to be implemented before doing any redirect etc.

for simple one page to other page redirection S2 provides a very elegant way where it will create an empty Action with execute method on run time and will always return `SUCCESS`this is what you need to do

```
<action name="Hello">
   // ...
</action>
```

in above case If the class attribute in an action mapping is left blank, the com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport class is used as a default.
For detail refer to this page [action-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/action-configuration.html)

Comment: Its giving error message "No action config found for the specified url."

this is my link <a href="first.do">First Page</a>

my struts config file is 

<struts-config>
    <action-mappings>
        <action name="first">
            <forward name="success" path="/FirstPage.jsp"></forward>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>     
</struts-config>

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to make a separate action for each URL in Struts 2. You can work with a single class, Just make separate functions for each link.

Example action definition in struts.xml:

```
<action name="Link1" class="com.project.YourActionClass" method="handleLink1">
            ........
</action>

<action name="Link2" class="com.project.YourActionClass" method="handleLink2">
           .........
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not required to create separate action class for each link, we just need  to configure the method name you would like to call on click on each link using the method attribute, one action class is sufficient and action mappings should be configured in struts.xml.

This is an advantage in struts2.xml, where as in struts1 I guess we need to use dispatch action in order to call a particular method.